# How to run python script on atom?

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm new to using atom and was wondering how to run a python script on it. I have code written at the moment which works perfectly fine in normal python shell, using tkinter, however when I run it through the command line, it says:

```
import tkinter as tk
ImportError: No module named tkinter
```

How do I fix this? In my environment variables I have already added python.exe, the file directory to the actual script I'm running and to the python download itself. How do I fix this?

Comment: Which version of python interpreter do you use in both cases?

Comment: Which package are you using for running python scripts in atom?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way is to load the Jupyter plugin. It's called Hydrogen. Then under the packages menu, you can select Hydrogen/Run all and it will run your python code. there is a keyboard shortcut for doing this which speeds up the process. You can easily check your code as you write it by using the hydrogen option to run a line and go to next line.

As for your Tkinter problem have you loaded Tkinter?  You can do this using pip install Tkinter. After that try running your code again.

Answer (score 0):

In python 2.7 and below, the modules's name is **T**kinter, while in 3.0 and above, it is **t**kinter.

Atom (whatever this is) seems to use a 2.7 or below version of python interpreter.

Comment: it wasn't what asked. atom needs a specific def to run python3 code